# Swift JSONEncoder encoding generic type with custom structure

Tags: json, swift, generics, encoding

I am currently trying to encode a generic struct (`T`) which has an attribute of this type with `JSONEncoder`:

```
struct A <T:Codable> : Codable {
    var id: Int
    var attribute : T
    
    init(id: Int, attribute: T){
        self.id = id
        self.attribute = attribute
    }
    
}

struct B : Codable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}
```

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let foo = A<B>(id: 1, attribute: B(name: "name", age: 29))

try? encoder.encode(foo)
```

This results in a JSON like this:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "attribute" : {
    "name" : "name",
    "age" : 29
  }
}
```

But i would like to customize the encoding to get the nested attributes to the root level:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "name",
  "age" : 29
}
```

Using a custom `CodingKey` struct didn't work for me because `T` might have any number of attributes and the keys (names of attributes) are not known in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would need to be done manually, by implementing `encode(to:)` and `init(from:)`:

```
struct A <T:Codable> {
    var id: Int
    var attribute : T
}
```

```
extension A: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey { case id }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
       // use attribute's own encode(to:)
       try attribute.encode(to: encoder) 

       // then encode the id
       var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
       try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // use attribute's own init(from:)
        self.attribute = try T.init(from: decoder)
        
        // decode the id
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    }
}
```

---

**Note, that this is a very brittle solution. I WOULD NOT recommend encoding it the way you planned.**.

It easily breaks at run-time, with an error: `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`, if `T`'s encoding container differs from `A`'s (which is a *keyed container*)

For example, the following fails at run-time:

```
let a = A(id: 1, attribute: "A")
let data = JSONEncoder().encode(a)
```

This is because when `T` is a `String`, its container is a `SingleValueEncodingContainer`. Same would happen if `T` was an array:

```
let a = A(id: 1, attribute: ["A"])
```

because an array is encoded with an `UnkeyedEncodingContainer`